# GitHub Pages website rendering locally but not on server

Tags: css, github-pages

I am developing a personal website at https://kajalv.com. I made a number of changes now and they look fine locally. (Also, downloading the repo and opening index.html works fine.) But when I pushed to my master repository at https://github.com/kajalv/kajalv.github.io, some CSS seems to have been lost.

For example, this works locally but the change isn't visible on the actual site -

```
#contactContainer img
{
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: .5;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Similarly, a paragraph font color is set to black but this change isn't reflected on the site:

```
.eduInfo p
{
  color: black;
}
```

Another issue is my favicon. I can see it when I open the index.html file locally, but not on the actual site. I have set it using this code.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

I checked to see if I had any uncommitted changes, but there were none:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I have a number of such changes, but I'm assuming they are all the same issue. What could be the problem? Could this be an issue with GitHub Pages using my changes very slowly?

Comment: Everything you've listed is showing up fine when I visit the page. All the CSS is there when I inspect it. Only the `box-shadow` doesn't work because you've formatted the value wrong, and the `color:black` doesn't work because it's overridden by the value in `.eduInfo p.eduDetails` and `.eduInfo p.eduName`. I would suggest hard reloading the page and seeing if that helps. It also shows up in the repo, so I would assume this is your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a look at your last commit and I can see these changes on your page. I can also see the favicon you have in the repo on the page.

If the changes are working correctly locally and not on GH pages, just give it some time. It's a caching problem. Usually, it takes GH pages few minutes to update. You can also try with emptying the browser cache, in Chrome, you can open the Dev Tools -> Application -> Clear storage -> [Check everything] -> Clear site data. Or, with Dev Tools open, you can right click on the refresh button and choose Empty Cache and Hard Reload.

For extra measure, you can check Disable cache in the Network tab, although this doesn't clear the cache in all cases, so don't rely solely on this feature.

If that doesn't work, you try with private browsing mode, but make sure you close the session between updates to make sure the cache is cleared.

P.S.: Your page looks really cool, great job :)

Comment: Thank you! I did what you said and it looks fine now. I guess it was a caching problem after all.

Answer (score 3):

I checked your site out and all the css you listed was rendering correctly for me. It could be a matter of your browser simply caching the css file, in which case a hard-refresh (cmd-shift-r on Mac Chrome, ctrl & click refresh on Windows Chrome) would fix it.

In my experience GitHub pages can sometimes take a couple of minutes to update too.

Comment: Thank you! A hard refresh worked. It looks fine now.

Answer (score 0):

check the Opacity value of the CSS on the deployed page. You might see it as only set to 1%, rather than the .5 you set this to.

If so this isn't an issue with GitHub pages, but an issue with the minified build code compiled by the bundler. This was the issue I had using a create-react-app.

You can find more information here

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7980